# QT5 GUI black drop down on some of the options in toolbar when run inside docker container

Tags: docker, qt5

**Problem:**

I created a Qt5 GUI and tried to run it inside the docker container. When I run the docker container, it'll execute an entrypoint.sh file, which will run the GUI inside the container.

The command I run is

```
docker run -d --network=host -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix --device=/dev/fuse --cap-add SYS_ADMIN --security-opt apparmor:unconfined <image_name>
```

And the GUI pops up and when I click on the menu options, I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNacq.png) (red regions are something that I can't show). There's no error or anything, I just can't see it. Each time I run the command, different option's drop down become black. Any suggestions?